# How much faster does Striker style charge Hunting Arts?

Tags: monster-hunter-generations

In MHGen, the Striker hunting style is all about arts. You can equip more, and it charges them faster. How much faster does Striker charge arts?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't, or at least not directly.

I tested this with a Switch Axe.

When using Guild style, Energy Charge II takes 12 sword mode hits to fully charge.

When using Striker style, Energy Charge II still takes 12 sword mode hits to fully charge. However, you also gain charge when taking damage; the more damage, the more charge.